# Faster Jackson can't be this dumb (line endings)

Tags: java, jackson

I'm working with some existing code that uses a regular Jackson mapper and reads in a line from a JSON file like this:

```
mapper.readValue(line, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
```

The json itself is pretty large and technically it's not well formatted because the file contains json like this (no comma's between massive json objects):

{...}

{...}

{...}

I put some 'returns' a.k.a line endings into the first object to better be able to read it so now it looks like:
{..., ...,

...., ...}

{...}

{...}

You know just kind of indenting a little to be able to at least read it.

The moment I did that my unit test started failing with this:

```
Unexpected end-of-input within/between Object entries
```

It's been a while since I had to deal with Jackson at this low a level. I'm assuming normally it would ignore the EOL character if it comes across some thing like:

{"key":"value",

"key":"value"...

}

So does it have to do with the `TypeReference` setup being used?

Comment: Jackson is not dumb. It simply can't work when you give it a bad input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That TypeReference wants to produce a Map, which would typically come from a single Json object with named properties, not a list of independent objects separated by \n.

And of course, a file containing json objects separated by \n is not valid json.

If you have code that is reading each line...up to the next \n then passing that single object to Jackson to parse, then adding \n within an object would cause your code to start sending partial objects to Jackson, producing errors like you are seeing.

Can't say if this is what's happening for you, but it's the first idea that comes to mind.

Comment: Yeah I don't know why I didn't think of the fact it's parsing line by line. I guess I immediately thought it was the mapper as I haven't encountered code that uses a bufferedReader to read json files in a long time. That's exactly what it is. Putting in the \n means the bufferedReader only gets that line. <face palm>